# In shell script, storing an output into an array inside case statement

Tags: arrays, shell

I wanted to store an output into a array in a shell script which is called inside a case statement. I am running on Bash Version 3.2.39. Windriver Linux.

The command I used is files_array_out=( $(ls | grep test) )

This command works fine and stores output into a array, when it is defined outside the case statement. If the same command is called inside the case statement, the output is not stored in a array. It stores the output as a single variable with new line in between.

Ex: I created 3 files test1, test2 , test3. And this is the example I used

#!/bin/bash

#####Outside case statement

files_array_out=( $(ls | grep test) )
echo "Outside Case statement: first element of test files is ${files_array_out[0]}"

#

Inside case statement

echo "Enter 1"

IFS="";read a

case "$a" in
        "1") files_array=( $(ls | grep test) )
                echo "Inside Case statement: first element is ${files_array[0]}"
        ;;
esac

---

Output i got after running is: 
 sh check.sh 
Outside Case statement: first element of test files is test1
Enter 1
1
Inside Case statement: first element is test1
test2
test3

Could anyone help me with this problem. Why the output is different inside and outside case statement when same command is used?. How to get the same output when command is used inside the case statement?

Comment: Please learn how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In this code, you could create a function `cmd(){ echo 1; echo 2; }` and set `mode=1` and `tc=esw`, and show how you are echoing the result.  Then we would be able to understand what you're seeing better, and either reproduce it or not, and pontificate on why you're seeing what you're seeing.  As it is, we're reduced to guesswork, which is not good.

Comment: Running under Bash (3.2.57 on Mac OS X), adding three lines after the augmented script suggested in my previous comment: (1_ `echo "${array[@]}"`, (2)
`echo "${#array[@]}"` and (3)
`echo "0 = [${array[0]}]; 1 = [${array[1]}]"`, I get the output lines: (1) `something`, (2)
`1 2`, (3)
`2`, (4)
`0 = [1]; 1 = [2]`.  What do you get?  How do you get it?  Which shell are you using on which platform?